# C# MongoDB driver only returning 100 results

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq, azure-cosmosdb

I am writing a mailing label, and need to print a label for each document.

I have 829 documents on the Collection, but when I retrieve them, I only get 100 documents.

I have this LINQ code:

```
IMongoCollection Pessoa;
Pessoa = database.GetCollection<Pessoa>(collectionName);

return Pessoa.AsQueryable().ToList();
```

How to retrieve ALL the documents?

Comment: return Pessoa.AsQueryable().OrderBy(d => d.Nome).ToList(); stills retrieve only 100 documents.

Comment: Maybe you have a `Limit` setted anywhere?

Comment: Do all of the objects have a value in the Nome attribute?

Comment: Yes, all have the Nome attribute filled. No Limit setted anywhere.

Comment: I updated the command to     return Pessoa.AsQueryable().ToList();  // Stills loads only 100 documents

Comment: Assuming `Pessoa` is collection, `AsQueryable()` results in aggregation framework call. Could you check if one of [these methods](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/reading/) suit you?

Comment: Hey, it works if I use the find method, then it returns All the records.. Is there someway to retrieve All the records using the AsQueryable?

Answer (score 2):

> I have 829 documents on the Collection, but when I retrieve them, I only get 100 documents.

I could reproduce the issue on my side, using AsQueryable extension method on IMongoCollection `collection.AsQueryable()` to find documents in a collection, which always return 100 documents even though I changed **Items per page** setting to Unlimited on Azure portal.

Setting:

[image]

Test code:

[image]

Count documents in query explorer:

[image]

To query all the documents in a collection, as you mentioned in comment, you could try to call [Find method](http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-csharp-driver/2.4/reference/driver/crud/reading/#finding-documents) with an empty filter.

Comment: I tested and confirm that this Default behaviour of returning 100 documents also happens on a non Microsoft Server, as Mongo Atlas.

Answer (score 2):

You're probably being limited by the default [cursor BatchSize](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/cursor.batchSize/).
You can modify this behaviour passing an `AggregateOptions` object to the `AsQueryable` extension and setting the `BatchSize` property to a large enough value.

```
public static IMongoQueryable<TDocument> AsQueryable<TDocument>(this IMongoCollection<TDocument> collection, AggregateOptions aggregateOptions = null)
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the question useful, so I wrote a convenient `IEnumerator`:

```cs
        private sealed class MongoCollectionEnumerator : IEnumerator<T> {
            private IMongoCollection<T> _collection;
            private IAsyncCursor<T> _cursor; // outer enumerator
            private IEnumerator<T> _currentBatchEnumerator; // inner enumerator

            public MongoCollectionEnumerator(IMongoCollection<T> collection) {
                _collection = collection;

                InternalInit();
            }

            #region interface implementation
            T IEnumerator<T>.Current {
                get {
                    return _currentBatchEnumerator.Current;
                }
            }

            object IEnumerator.Current {
                get {
                    return ThisAsTypedIEnumerator.Current;
                }
            }

            bool IEnumerator.MoveNext() {
                if (_currentBatchEnumerator != null) {
                    if (_currentBatchEnumerator.MoveNext()) {
                        return true;
                    }
                }

                // inner not initialized or already at end
                if (_cursor.MoveNext()) {
                    // advance the outer and defer back to the inner by recursing
                    _currentBatchEnumerator = _cursor.Current.GetEnumerator();
                    return ThisAsIEnumerator.MoveNext();
                }
                else { // outer cannot advance, this is the end
                    return false;
                }
            }

            void IEnumerator.Reset() {
                InternalCleanUp();
                InternalInit();
            }
            #endregion

            #region methods private
            // helper properties to retrieve an explicit interface-casted this
            private IEnumerator ThisAsIEnumerator => this;
            private IEnumerator<T> ThisAsTypedIEnumerator => this;

            private void InternalInit() {
                var filterBuilder = new FilterDefinitionBuilder<T>();
                _cursor = _collection.Find(filterBuilder.Empty).ToCursor();
            }

            private void InternalCleanUp() {
                if (_currentBatchEnumerator != null) {
                    _currentBatchEnumerator.Reset();
                    _currentBatchEnumerator = null;
                }

                if (_cursor != null) {
                    _cursor.Dispose();
                    _cursor = null;
                }
            }
            #endregion

            #region IDisposable implementation
            private bool disposedValue = false; // To detect redundant calls

            private void InternalDispose(bool disposing) {
                if (!disposedValue) {
                    if (disposing) {
                        InternalCleanUp();

                        _collection = null;
                    }

                    disposedValue = true;
                }
            }

            void IDisposable.Dispose() {
                InternalDispose(true);
            }
            #endregion
        }
```