# Cannot find any element which order number greater than 100. Spring Data MongoDB

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-data

Spring Data MongoDB `find` don't work if order number is greater than 100.

I have about 170k documents in my db and when I am trying to find some element which order number is greater than 100, I get null, if order number <= 100, I get this object. Also with invoking `findAll()` method, only 100 documents returns. All works fine with MongoDB Shell.

Here is my config

```
  server:
     data:
        mongodb:
            host: 192.168.100.14
               port: 27017
               database: myApp
```

Repository

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Repository;

public interface DictionaryResultRepository extends MongoRepository<MyClass, String> {


}
```

Data class

```
import lombok.Data;
import lombok.Getter;
import lombok.Setter;
import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

import java.util.List;

@Data
@Getter
@Setter
public class MyClass {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String text;

    private List<MyAnotherClass> lst;
}
```

Comment: Better post the service and repository layers including the data objects.

Comment: @Nikolas ok, will provide, for now found only this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43498012/c-sharp-mongodb-driver-only-returning-100-results

Comment: Problem was in config... Should be "spring" instead of "server" xD, don't really understand this behavior, but it is solved